# How to compare "null" json values in python

Tags: python

One of my APIs give a json output

```
{"student":{"id": null}}
```

I tried comparing this null value in the following ways but none is working

```
 if(student['id'] == "null")
 if(student['id'] == None)
 if(student['id'] == null)
```

What is the correct way to compare null values?

Full code:

```
 students = [{"id":null},{"id":1},{"id":3}]   
 for student in students:
     if(student['id'] is not None):
         print("found student" + str(student['id']))
         break
```

Answer (score 20):

**Solution:**

Use `None`

```
>>> import json
>>> b = json.loads('{"student":{"id": null}}')
>>> b['student']['id'] is None
True
```

**Original Problem:**

This assignment looks like JSON but it's not (it's a *native* Python array with *native* Python dictionaries inside):

```
students = [{"id":null},{"id":1},{"id":3}]
```

This won't work because `null` does not exist in Python.

JSON data would come in a string:

```
students = '[{"id":null},{"id":1},{"id":3}]'
```

And you have to parse it using the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> parsed_students = json.loads(students)
>>> print(parsed_students)
[{'id': None}, {'id': 1}, {'id': 3}]
```

Notice how `null` became `None`

Comment: well I tried this `if(student['id'] is not None): print("not null")` but it's not working. Not sure why.

Comment: What error do you get? What is 'student' in your scope? Paste a bit more code before that if statement here.

Comment: I see. 'null' does not exist in Python. Your first line is not JSON, it's a Python array. Enclose it in single quote marks and then parse it using json.loads (see the second line in my answer above)

Comment: well this array is stored in a variable and is an output of some other function. How can I enclose it in ' ' ?

Comment: Can I use `json.loads(student_array_element)` eg: json.loads(student)` inside the for loop before the if statement

Comment: The output from your API should be a string with a JSON object or array in it, right? Parse it into Python objects with json.loads. Check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110929/discussion-between-love2code-and-carlos-mermingas).

Comment: if students = [{"id":null},{"id":1},{"id":3}]  it works well. How bout students = {"id":null},{"id":1},{"id":3}? json.loads(..) never works.

Comment: Assuming that both of these are strings, the first one is a list and the second one is not valid json. Check this spec: https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

**Working code**

Most of the case in python we can't compare abc = 'null' for json null values
so we should use some hack which `json.loads()` gives use i.e `json.loads()` provide None value for json null values. So use as below;

```
 #Check for null value as wel as json null value 
        if existing_tags_str and json.loads(existing_tags_str) is not None:
            print("dosomething")
```